# I'm facing this error after replaying the nodeos, towards the very end block. Can anybody please explain and suggest me something?

Tags: nodeos, testnet, private-blockchain, plugin

I've used this command for replaying on **single local testnode** and my nodeos version is **2.0.1**

```
sudo nodeos --replay-blockchain -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --plugin eosio::state_history_plugin --contracts-console --disable-replay-opts --verbose-http-errors --state-history-dir /shpdata --trace-history --chain-state-history --access-control-allow-origin='*'
```

ERROR:

```
 error 2020-08-10T15:04:24.960 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:1796      schedule_production_ ] Failed to start a pending block, will try again later
    warn  2020-08-10T15:04:25.010 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:1487      start_block          ] 3060000 database_exception: Database exception
    db revision is not on par with head block
        {"db.revision()":12681492,"controller_head_block":12681493,"fork_db_head_block":12681493}
        nodeos  controller.cpp:1522 start_block
```

Please guide me. Thank you!
[image: Error image]